# Multiple Windows PCs respecting each other's accounts

Tags: windows, networking, resources

I've run to this problem several times before and it is really bothering me.

Is there a way to tell windows to respect another comupter accounts? I have let's say 2 computers and each has some user accounts. Now I would like to give access to my resources only to the selected and properly authenticated users of the second computer meaning I trust its administrator and can rely on him.

I am aware that if I had windows server I could set up a domain and that would be a lot easier, but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of your ability to implement it or not, a shared authentication domain is the solution for this problem and there are no elegant alternatives.

Comment: An inelegant alternative is to create the accounts (with same passwords) on both machines. It sucks, but it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the way is to put accounts with the same names and passwords on all machines. That's the only way, short of implementing a domain.

Comment: Well I don't think that it changes anything.. How to set permission to a folder in that case ?

Comment: Say you're on Machine A, Bob is on Machine B. You want to give him rights to your C:\Windows folder. Share it and assign permission to the Bob account that exists on your machine. Assuming the username and password are the same, when he tried to connect, he will have the proper rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can give access to `otherpc\username` or `username@otherpc`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to pick up a cheap NAS (buffalo, etc) and put shared resources there.  You'd be able to set up whatever permissions & users you like, within the NAS.